# Should I cache Firebase idTokens for a while, after I authenticated it in node admin sdk?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am building an app, where I need to use my own backend besides Firebase. I need to authenticate a logged-in user in my backend too. So I found [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/how-to-use-firebase-auth-with-a-custom-node-backend-99a106376c8a) which does this. I send an idToken and verify this header in admin sdk in my node, based on the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). I thought I could cache this token with redis or just a js map after the first verification for 10 minutes or as much as a user session would take, to speed things up, instead of verifying each request in a 10 min sess. I could probably cache the token in the phone too for some time?

My question is, what security consequences would this bring? Thank you.

To clarify I am not using custom tokens, I will be using the built in Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is to send the ID token to your backend with every request.  It's not expensive to [verify the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) with the Admin SDK as shown in that documentation.  It doesn't cost any money.

Typically what you're supposed to do is use a listener to detect when the ID token changes (it will be refreshed automatically every hour), and keep using that token until the SDK delivers a new one to your callback.  In web clients, you're supposed to use [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) to register a callback to get changes to this token over time.  There is no need to persist or cache this token - simply use whatever the callback most recently provided.

Comment: Oookay I think I understand both of you. So verifying a token does not at all send a verify request to fb's servers, but since its a jwt it can do it locally on my own server? All I need to care about is what token I get on the client and I (of course) send it to my backend on each request? But even there I shouldn't complicate it, just use fb' functions to get the token?

Comment: Yes, it's a JWT and just needs to be decoded and checked on your backend.

Comment: for me it took so long to verify the idtoken. the node server will even timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the Firebase backend services keep a small cache of recent ID tokens, and their decoded results. So if they receive the exact same token, they'll use the already decoded result. This is a riskless operation, as the decoding operation is idempotent: the same input will always deliver the same output.

Comment: Yes I am sure they use cache, but I want to spare requests to Firebase's backends

Comment: Decoding and verifying a token does not require a request to Firebase's backends. What does require a request is getting the public keys, but that's a cacheable resource too (just like the decoded token).

Comment: Okay I think I understand! Verifying a token doesn't make a request to fb, its just a calculation.